# Add Jar file to GWT source path?

Tags: inheritance, gwt, module

I have some JAR file, I need to reference it from GWT Source package.
How can I accomplish that? should I create module and inherit it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit long and complex so I'll put some checks you need to do:

1. The jar file MUST be GWT compatible
   (needs to have a .gwt.xml file with
   an entry-point defined)
2. You need to add an `<inherits name='myExtensionFullPath'
   />`
3. If you use Eclipse make sure the jar file is in the "BuildPath" (/war/WEB-INF/lib is a good place)

If the Jar is not compatible with GWT, then you'll need to have it in your server side and wrap it to be called with GWT-RPC.

Hope it helps.